# How to Get a Dynamics 365CE Personal Development Environment?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I'm learning Microsoft Dynamics 365CE online and I'd like a personal environment to try out development on. Is there a way to do this without paying for a full licenced environment?

I'm not going to use this for production, only personal education.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a **free** 30 days trial & use it for personal development/learning purpose in full fledged CRM online environment.

Proceed to the [Dynamics 365 trial sign-up page](https://portal.office.com/Signup?OfferId=bd569279-37f5-4f5c-99d0-425873bb9a4b&dl=DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1&Culture=en-us&Country=us&flight=AdminOnCustomization&ali=1) & signup.

[Step by step instructions](https://support.clickdimensions.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001168154-Sign-up-for-a-Dynamics-365-trial).

Answer (score 2):

USE INCOGNITO MODE ONLY!!! (Or Private Browsing in IE/Edge). 
Dynamics is like Cookie Monster – does everything according to what cookies exist and isn’t very smart about it. You WILL get routed via whatever cookies are found at the most critical "Set up" step later on if you do not use Incognito/Private Browsing mode!!!

1.) Go to https://trials.dynamics.com

2.) Choose the "Sign up here" link in the "Are you signing up on behalf of a customer or using this trial for development purposes?" area.

3.) Choose "No, continue signing up."

4.) Fill out the "Welcome, let’s get to know you" screen normally. Don’t worry if you have used the E-mail/Phone before, it is fine.

5.) Fill out the "Create your user ID" area as normal. Click "Create my account."

6.) On the "Prove. You’re. Not. A. Robot. [sic]" screen you can reuse your cell number. Then click "Text me."

7.) You now have an Office.com trial and that means nothing so MAKE SURE you click "Set up" if you want Microsoft to set up the Dynamics 365 Org at all. Otherwise, you will have nothing. Also, again if you did not clear your cache or use Incognito/Private Browsing, the "Set up" button will route you to whatever cookies it finds and likes best. Click "Set up."

8.) On the "Let’s get your FREE 30-day trial set up" click the scenario that best fits you, otherwise choose "None of these. Don’t customize my organization." If you want the "traditional" CRM experience (Sales, Customer Service, Marketing, etc.). Also, BE AWARE that if you add any of the "scenarios" (ESPECIALLY "Field Service" and "Project Service Automation" you WILL HAVE DEPENDENCIES ON THESE MODULES!!!). This is crucially important if you are developing in this test Org so that you can export the Solution to another Org because….

IF THEY DO NOT HAVE "FIELD SERVICE" OR "PROJECT SERVICE AUTOMATION" YOUR IMPORT WILL FAIL!!!

*My thoughts are that as a general rule, if you are showing off all the bells-and-whistles of D365 go with "All of these" and if you are developing a Solution go with "None of these…"

9.) Click "Complete Setup."

10.)    Wait for the "Setting up…" screen to finish.

11.)    You now have an Org. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Another and more permenant option would be to create your own on premise environment using license keys provided by a msdn subsciption. The step by step is in the following link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGpw9fI-gIY