# Sandbox environment for Dynamics 365 learning

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm trying to study for the MB-200 exam and I'm using the Microsoft Learn resource to study.  I'm currently working through the [Apply goal management to Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/apply-goal-management-dynamics-365/).  In the [Exercise - Measuring customer success using goals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/define-track-goals-in-dynamics-365/4-measuring-customer-success-using-goals) it says:

1. In your Dynamics 365 Instance, go to Settings > Data Management.

I don't have an instance of Dynamics 365.

So my question is, is there a ready-made sandbox environment where everything is already setup, with the correct licenses and roles and security applied?

If no such sandbox is available, does this means I have to learn how to configure a Dynamics 365 instance before I can attempt the MB-200 exam?  As without a Dynamics 365 instance, it seems I can't do the exercises to study for MB-200.

Any pointers on how I should go about doing this will be greatly appreciated as I have tried creating a trial Dynamics 365 for Customer Service account, but it seems that is not enough, I need to configure licenses, and users, and roles before I can actually use the Customer Service app in Dynamics 365 trial.

It may be that I need to work towards a different exam before the MB-200 which helps me learn how to configure a Dynamics 365 instance.  If that is the case, could someone please let me know which exam that is.  Also, from the Microsoft Learn website, which learning path or module should I start to learn how to configure a Dynamics 365 instance for Customer Services before I can attempt the MB-200 exam?  I can't seem to find a learning path or module for configuring a Dynamics 365 instance from the Microsoft Learn website which is obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get a Dynamics 365CE Personal Development Environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725013/how-to-get-a-dynamics-365ce-personal-development-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Its really easy to provision a trial here:

https://trials.dynamics.com/

You just need to provide a URL and username and password (write them down!), and you have a fully working instance of Dynamics - You might want to provision just the Customer Service First party app for this particular exam.

Make sure you click on 'Are you signing up on behalf of a customer or using this trial for development purposes?' link.

You'll have a pre-configured Customer Engagement portal for 30 days (you'll automatically have admin access), after which you have the option to purchase it or delete it - No credit card details are needed. In addition you may go to the envrironment page and add any additional modules you may need in addition to the base install.

Good luck in your exam.

Comment: I've done this, but there is no pre-configured Customer Engagement portal.  Not sure where the environment page is either.  Do you have a link to the environment page so I can hopefully select Customer Engagement?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but you should start from PL-900 which is most suitable for you as a beginer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/power-plat-fundamentals/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/pl-900
then you should go for pl-400 ( old name MB-400 )
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/pl-400
Exam PL-400: Microsoft Power Platform Developer
there some awesome resource to learn theoretically or in some case they provide you sandbox as well after completing all those certifications then I suggest you pl-200 (old name MB-200)
here you can get a trial which will help you learn practically but there are so many things which you need professional license
https://trials.dynamics.com/
long story short dynamics 365 is a big platform that you can not learn just from trials or theoretical knowledge you have to do some internship or job to get a professional expericance which will help you to pass certifications.